# how to keep prompting the user for a new word

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So far I got this program to run but I got stock in this part: the program should keep prompting the user for a new word until a word representing a valid binary number is input by the user. I know I'm suppose to use a loop but I dont know where to put it.

```
package programming_assignment_1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programming_Assignment_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please imput a binary number : ");
        String binary;
        binary = sc.next();
        boolean isBinary = true;

        char[] values = binary.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++)
        {
                if( (values[i] != '0') && (values[i] != '1') )
                {
                isBinary = false;
                break;
                }
        }
        if(!isBinary)
        {
        System.out.println("this is not a binary number");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
            {
                 String consecutive1s = "111";
               if (binary.indexOf(consecutive1s) != -1)
            {
                System.out.println("accepted");
            }
            else
            {
              System.out.println("rejected");  
            }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    boolean accepted = false;
    while(!accepted) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       ...

       if(!isBinary) {
           System.out.println("this is not a binary number");
       } else {
           accepted = true;
           ...

       }
       ...

    } // while
} // main
```

Additionally, I am not sure about your "for" loop - it does not add anything to your program, since it is executed exactly once ...

Comment: if you are reading 1 number from user at a time and user enters multiple numbers then `scanner` outside while loop is going to make problems. I would suggest to create new scanner each time, i.e. to create it in while loop.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale Damn ;) that was my first approach, but then I thought it would be a good optimization to create the scanner only once and reuse it ...

Comment: thanks for you answer. I have tried this solution before but the program has to keep prompting the user only if the input is not a binary.

Comment: @user1663414: in that case, simply move the "accepted = true" to the beginning of the else{} branch of if(!isBinary). I have adjusted my code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Put your code under `do...while(..)` loop. Something like :

```
do {
  //read number
  //process number
  // if num valid or operation is finished break the loop using break
} while (condtion);
```

I would have provided solution using your code but it seems you are new and need to learn basic things in Java. So I gave you just hint.

Comment: I know, but I have tried the do while loop for the last 2 days  without any positive results. thanks